# Get the macro to be executed in LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

At the beginning, I create a class and accessor based on a macro as followed (this code his largely inspire from the book of Peter Seibel http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/ )

```
(defun slot->defclass-slot (spec)
  `(,spec :initarg ,(as-keyword spec) :accessor ,spec :initform 0))
(defmacro define-class (class-name class-slot)
  `(defclass ,class-name ()
       ,(mapcar #'slot->defclass-slot class-slot)))
```

When I use the macro to generate the class, i have no fixed slots. The slots could be "name" and "id", or it could be "name", "id" and "description".

After, I had generate a class definition with the macro, i want to make several instance of that class. And again, I try to build a function as generic as possible, because the number of the slots in the class is variable.

For example, if I create a class with two slots "name" and "id". I might be interested to use this command:

```
(defun myfunction (slots)    
`(make-instance 'myclass :name ,(first slots) :id ,(second slots)))
```

But, if my class has three slots "name","id" and "description", I might be interested to use this command:

```
(defun myfunction (slots)    
    `(make-instance 'myclass :name ,(first slots) :id ,(second slots) :description (third slots)))
```

Somehow, i succeed to define a function that creates a list with the command make-instance and the right number of slots. Here is how I proceed.
First I add in the macro definition a properties "slots" to the class that contains the list of slots.

```
(defmacro define-class (class-name class-slot id-slot)
  `(progn
     (eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
         (setf (get ',class-name 'slots) ',class-slot))
   (defclass ,class-name ()
      ,(mapcar #'slot->defclass-slot class-slot))
```

Then I could generate the command with the following text:

```
(defun make (slot-title slot-value)
  `(,(as-keyword slot-title) ,slot-value))
(defun list->db (slots-instance)
  `(make-instance 'model 
     ,@(mapcan #'make (get 'model 'slots) slots-instance)))) 
(defmacro make-model (myslots)
   (list->db myslots))
```

And when i execute list->db the following input ("a" "b"), i get the following result for example:

```
(make-instance 'myclass :name "a" :id "b")
```

But now, I wonder how i can make a function that take a list of list (e.g, (("k" "u") ("t" "j"))), and for each element of the list execute the command and create a class?

Comment: Can you explain what the title has to do with the question? Where is the macro? Why do you return a list? Why do you want to create a class, when your code doesn't do that?

Comment: I recommend clearifying your question first. You could give an example with sample input and output.Don't be encouraged by the downvotes. I have the feeling that you are just so new, that you have no idea how to express your questions clearly. So work on that, preferably by following my suggestion above.

Comment: The code is actually from http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-parsing-binary-files.html

Comment: I recommand this book, and I should have mentionned it. Now it's done.

Answer (score 3):

When you use backquote, you are creating a list, not executing it as an expression.  It is often used to create macros.  Macros transform code to other code.  Code is represented as lists in Lisp.

What you have written is equivalent to:

```
(defun myfunction (slots)
  (list 'make-instance ''myclass :name (first slots) :id (second slots)))
```

What you seem to intend is to just do it:

```
(defun myfunction (slots)
  (make-instance 'myclass :name (first slots) :id (second slots)))
```

This mistake seems to stem from rote application of things you have seen elsewhere without understanding it at all.  Don't do that.  You might benefit a lot from reading a good book, e. g. [Practical Common Lisp](http://gigamonkeys.com/book).